# Add short_description to accordion tabs on product page

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute, product-view, tabs

I have the following code which creates vertical accordion tabs on the product page - currently it 'fetches' the 'description' product attribute. I'd also like to fetch the 'short_description' product attribute (in a separate tab).

**LOCAL.XML**

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>short_description</alias><title>Short Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_shortdescription</block><template>catalog/product/view/shortdescription.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Range Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>upsell_products</alias><title>We Also Recommend</title><block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block><template>catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
 </block>
```

**TABS.PHTML**

```
                     <?php if($productpage_collateral == 'collateral_tabs_vertical'): ?>
             <div class="vertical">
                <div class="holder">
                    <div class="grid_3 alpha">
             <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="meigee-tabs">
                        <?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
                            <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
                                <li id="product_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>" class="<?php echo !$_index?' active first':''?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $_tab['title']?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                        <?php foreach ($custom_tabs as $key) {
                         if(!empty($key)):
                        ?>
                        <li id="<?php echo $key; ?>"><div class="tab-left"></div><a href="#"><?php echo Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($key)->getTitle(); ?></a><div class="tab-right"></div></li>
                        <?php endif; } ?>
                    </ul>
              <?php if($productpage_collateral == 'collateral_tabs_vertical'): ?>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_9 omega">
              <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
                        <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
                            <div class="meigee-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>_contents"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias']) ?></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php foreach ($custom_tabs as $key) {
                    if(!empty($key)):
                    ?>
                    <div class="meigee-tabs-content" id="<?php echo $key; ?>_contents"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId(trim($key))->toHtml() ?></div>
                    <?php endif; } ?>
            <?php if($productpage_collateral == 'collateral_tabs_vertical'): ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

**TABS.PHP**

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Tabs extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
protected $_tabs = array();

/**
 * Add tab to the container
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @param string $block
 * @param string $template
 */
function addTab($alias, $title, $block, $template)
{

    if (!$title || !$block || !$template) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->_tabs[] = array(
        'alias' => $alias,
        'title' => $title
    );

    $this->setChild($alias,
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock($block, $alias)
            ->setTemplate($template)
        );
}

function getTabs()
{
    return $this->_tabs;
}
}
```

I have added a shortdescription.phtml file in catalog/product/view folder and included this as per other items in XML. However, I receive the following error.

**Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Tabs.php**

Comment: Where do you want to add the short description? If you want to add it in the same page the the description then that should be enough $_product->getShortDescription();

Comment: Thanks Klettseb. I'd like the short description to appear in a tab on the product page. Code updated above with what I tried and the error received.

Comment: Check in your Tabs.php where the function setTemplate() is called and update this to the question please . Thanks